# Unable to render output in flask. Exception with returning flask json.dumps on list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am having trouble in displaying output in JSON using Flask. I am calling a function that returns a list of lists which looks as:

```
[[["High", 0], ["Medium", 1], ["Low", 2], ["Unknown", 3]], ["test_data", [4155, 1, 25, 9.1, 2, "2.40"]], ["label", 1]]
```

However, in my flask application, I am unable to `jsonify` or `json.dumps`. I do like this:

```
def remotely_call_func(json_lol):
    # print('inside remotely')
        # abc =[]
        # abc=ext.call_func(json_lol) # I tried to jsonify abc

        # print(abc) # print the 
        return json.dumps(ext.call_func(json_lol)) # throws an exception
        # return ext.call_func(json_lol)

@app.route('/api/v1/engine/label', methods=['POST'])
def labelJsonHandler():
    if request.is_json:
        # Parse the JSON into a Python dictionary
        print('request is json')
        content = request.get_json()  # --works
        app.logger.info("labelJsonHandler()..", content)
        return access_data_api(content['orderId']), 200  # Return a string along with an HTTP status code

    else:
        return "Request was not JSON", 400
```

The exception that I get is:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2020 05:20:34] "POST /api/v1/engine/label HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
 File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\nma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2098, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

I am able to receive the exact list of lists in my flask application. How can render this as JSON to POST using my flask?

Comment: Why have you hashed out half of your code? You need to give a [mcve]. If the hashed-out code is not relevant - don't post it.

Comment: problem in such cases is when one of your function returns none, which probably is `json_lol` in your case

Comment: the `json_lol` from `remotely_call_func(json_lol)` prints the value that is being received correctly. The issue is how can I display it in json in flask